# how to get a list of all years from the mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+------------+---------------+------------+
| date       | other_columns | date2      |
+------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-05-23 | #             | 2018-04-12 |
+------------+---------------+------------+
| 2013-04-08 | #             | null       |
+------------+---------------+------------+
| 2007-11-11 | #             | 2019-09-13 |
+------------+---------------+------------+
```

there is such a table in mySQL, with several thousand rows. how can I get out of there only years without requesting the entire base. I just can’t figure out how to do this.

```
[2019,
2018,
2013,
2007]
```

I would like to extract them something like this, I will be glad to any advice

Comment: I'm sorry, but saying `I don’t know how to google.` just sounds like you're not even trying. Search StackOverflow for `[mysql] EXTRACT` and read any referenced links to MySQL query or function syntax.

Comment: What is the data type of `date` and `date2` fields?

Comment: *how can I get out of there only years without requesting the entire base.* If indices by `date` and `date2` fields or an index by `(date, date2)` not exists then there is no way to get the requested data WITHOUT ACCESSING THE TABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `year()` and `union all`:

```
select distinct year(date)
from (select date from t union all
      select date2 from t
     ) t;
```

If you want this as a single concatenated string, I would recommend:

```
select group_concat(yyyy order by yyyy) as years
from (select year(date) as yyyy from t
      union -- intentionally remove duplicates
      select year(date2) from t
     ) t;
```